# IEEE standards household electronics

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer

I'm new to the community, and new to building electronics in general. I am mainly concerned with grounding of line voltage transformers -- I am sure there is some IEEE standard on this but I have not been able to discover the appropriate regulation.

Does anyone know where to start looking for household electronic standards? I have wired three phase 120V to a manufactured power supply, but I want to start modifying my own power supplies and I wish to do so safely.

Thank you in advance, I know I will have to do my own research I just do not know where to start.

Ben

Comment: If you're interested in safety, look for UL and IEC standards, not IEEE.

Comment: And don't play with mains until you know exactly what you're doing.